# Sorting a list and give each item a new sorting index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, razor

Lets say I have 3 menu-items. Each one have (eg) 5 links inside. So I have a something like this:

```
//This is just some test-code. normally i''ll get the data from a database
List<NavigationModel> navigation = new List<NavigationModel>();
Random randomInt = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    NavigationModel m = new NavigationModel();
    m.MenuName = "Users";
    m.LinkName = "Link (" + i + ")";
    m.ControllerName = "AAA";
    m.ActionName = "Function" + i;
    m.SortingMenu = 5;

    navigation.Add(m);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    NavigationModel m = new NavigationModel();
    m.MenuName = "Help";
    m.LinkName = "Link (" + i + ")";
    m.ControllerName = "BBB";
    m.ActionName = "Function" + i;
    m.SortingMenu = 10;

    navigation.Add(m);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    NavigationModel m = new NavigationModel();
    m.MenuName = "Home";
    m.LinkName = "Link (" + i + ")";
    m.ControllerName = "CCC";
    m.ActionName = "Function" + i;
    m.SortingMenu = 2;

    navigation.Add(m);
}

navigation = navigation.OrderBy(x => x.SortingMenu).ToList();
```

As you can see I'll get 3 menu-items with correct sorting BUT I need the sorting started by 0 followed by 1,2 ...

How can I do this without hardcoding or a database update command?

Comment: Assuming the sorting is stable, you'll need to sort first by 2, then by 1, then by 0 (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: I'm still unsure what you are trying to achieve.  However you don't need 3 loops, you could refactor this by using a single loop and declare multiple `NavigationModel` objects inside.

Comment: @Nolonar My 3 item got this sorting values: (5,10,2). And after the lambda sorting i'll get (2,5,10). Anyway, i want this sorting change to this values: (0,1,2)

Comment: Is it possible to do a `navigation[0].SortingMenu` command to get the value of `SortingMenu` in a specific item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LukeHennerleys answer is probably of a higher standard but I would rather change the value of SortingMenu with a simple `for-loop`. This should do the trick if you have the list sorted already.

```
for (int i = 0; i < navigation.Count; i++)
{
    navigation[i].SortingMenu = i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select` to bring out indexes after calling `OrderBy`. `Select((x, i))` where `i` will be your index.

```
public class TestObject
{
  public string A { get; set; }
  public int Index { get; set; }
}
public void Example()
{
  List<TestObject> testObjects = new List<TestObject>();
  testObjects.Add(new TestObject() { A = "B" });
  testObjects.Add(new TestObject() { A = "C" });
  testObjects.Add(new TestObject() { A = "A" });
  var objects = testObjects.OrderBy(x => x.A).Select((x, i) => new TestObject() { A = x.A, Index = i });
}
```